# won't verify a simple code

Tags: c++

When I tried to verify a simple “Hello world” program I get the following message:

```
class hardwareSerial has no member named printin.
```

What does it mean?

Comment: pretty simple fix here, but in the future, please post your code as well as any errors.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `println` instead of `printin`.  It stands for **print** **l**i**n**e.